# Is sqlite3_exec callback synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, sqlite, synchronous

Does the **Sqlite3** function `sqlite3_exec()` with a callback parameters runs synchonously or asynchronously ?

Example call:

```
int retStatus = sqlite3_exec(pDB, "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Something='Hi'", callback, &object, &error);

...Next line(s) of code...
```

- Synchronous: sqlite3_exec line is executed , then callback is called,
  then the next line(s) of code is executed.
- Asynchonous: sqlite3_exec line is executed , the next line(s) of code
  is executed and at some point the callback is called.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Synchronous. The callback is called for each row found before code continues:

```
static int _getName(void* pNames, int columns, char** data, char** columnNames)
{
    if (columns < 2)
    {
        assert(false && "Function called on wrong table!");
        // Signify failure
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<std::string>* vNames = static_cast< std::vector<std::string>* >(pNames);
    vNames->push_back(data[1]);
    // Success:
    return 0;
}

{
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    // assume pDB is a valid, opened sqlite3* db
    char* error = 0;
    if (sqlite3_exec(pDB, "SELECT * FROM TableNames", _getName, static_cast<void*>(&names), &error) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // log and free error:
    }

    assert(names.size() && "No entries were found in the table");
}
```

`_getName` will be called on every entry found in the table `TableNames`. If no entries are found, the function won't be called, and there will be no error. If you have table called TableNames that has 10 entries, then `names.size() == 10`. `_getName` will no longer be called if it returns non-zero

Comment: This is not exactly my question. My question is if something will be executed between the sqlite3_exec call and the callback call - I can trust that no single program step will be done between the sqlite3_exec call and the last callback for the last query item...

Comment: @Mendes: have you figured out the answer? Thanks. I think it is synchronous because of the way they call `sqlite3_close()` after exec, in most of examples.

Comment: It is synchronous.